# The float type can hold up to 38 figures and the double one can hold up to 300 figures. Where do these magic numbers come from?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I am reading "Teach yourself Java in 24 hours" and found the following statement.

[image]

There is no explanation how these magic numbers were determined in the book. 
How do they come?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: The precise values come from how the underlying bits are assigned meaning.

Comment: Very poor quality citation. It doesn't use standard terminology; doesn't specify the radix properlyl; doesn't specify the precision; gave rise to this question; ... Find yourself a better resource. Hint: you can neither teach yourself nor even learn Java in 24 hours. Or anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max numeric value a `float` can take is about `+3.4 * 10^38`.

The max numeric value of a `double` is about `1.7 * 10^308` (not accounting for the special "positive infinity" value).

With "figures", the author probably meant the max *magnitude* in the terms of the power of 10.

In other words, the author probably meant the *max count of meaningful nonfractional decimal digits* in a number representable by `float` or `double`.

Comment: The number of _significant figures_ about 7 decimal digits for `float`, and about 15 decimal digits for `double`.

Comment: Considering integral values only. The situation for numbers with fractional parts is considerably more complicated. @KevinAnderson

Comment: @EJP precision - min exponent - 1 is the position of last (decimal) digit after fraction point - that's 1074 places after fraction point for double precision, but that's only 751 digits if we omit leading zeros and use a 4.94065645841...e-324 notation. Single precision left as an exercize